# TkinterMapview is there a method to wait untill the map is fully loaded?

Tags: python, customtkinter, tkintermapview

In my Tkinter GUI, I want to set a specific position and a certain zoom level before taking a screenshot of the map for subsequent actions. The challenge I'm facing is finding a way to wait until the map is fully loaded before proceeding with the screenshot. I would aldo like to erase the visibility of the zoom buttons before the screenshot.

I've experimented with various methods such as time.sleep and invoking the screenshot function using Tkinter's after() method. However, these approaches seem to freeze the GUI. As a result, even though time passes before the screenshot is taken, the map stops loading. Therefore, even if I wait for a minute, the map's appearance remains unchanged.

Comment: have you tried to use threading ? It will at least resolve the freezing GUI + you can wait for the thread to end and then take the screenshot. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#threading-model)